# zramswapon failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, zram

When I try to enable the `zram` service on a machine with 32 cores, it fails when the number of devices is greater than 26.
Also, I do not see any configuration file, only `zramctl` utility with no obvious choice listed for the issue I am facing.

```
light-18-pro:~ # lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    300G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    500M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     35G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0    1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda4   8:4    0     10G  0 part /home
└─sda5   8:5    0  223.5G  0 part /data
sr0     11:0    1      4G  0 rom  
zram0  253:0    0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram1  253:1    0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram2  253:2    0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram3  253:3    0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram4  253:4    0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram5  253:5    0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram6  253:6    0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram7  253:7    0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram8  253:8    0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram9  253:9    0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram10 253:10   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram11 253:11   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram12 253:12   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram13 253:13   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram14 253:14   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram15 253:15   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram16 253:16   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram17 253:17   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram18 253:18   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram19 253:19   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram20 253:20   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram21 253:21   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram22 253:22   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram23 253:23   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram24 253:24   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram25 253:25   0 1002.3M  0 disk [SWAP]
zram26 253:26   0 1002.3M  0 disk 
zram27 253:27   0 1002.3M  0 disk 
zram28 253:28   0 1002.3M  0 disk 
zram29 253:29   0 1002.3M  0 disk 
zram30 253:30   0 1002.3M  0 disk 
zram31 253:31   0 1002.3M  0 disk
```

The error message is:

```
light-18-pro:~ # systemctl status zramswap.service 
● zramswap.service - Service enabling compressing RAM with zRam
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/zramswap.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-03-09 09:59:46 CET; 2h 13min ago
  Process: 2048 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zramswapon (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 2048 (code=exited, status=255)

Mar 09 09:59:46 light-18-pro zramswapon[2048]: swapon: /dev/zram26: swapon failed: Operation not permitted
Mar 09 09:59:46 light-18-pro zramswapon[2048]: swapon: /dev/zram27: swapon failed: Operation not permitted
Mar 09 09:59:46 light-18-pro zramswapon[2048]: swapon: /dev/zram28: swapon failed: Operation not permitted
Mar 09 09:59:46 light-18-pro zramswapon[2048]: swapon: /dev/zram29: swapon failed: Operation not permitted
Mar 09 09:59:46 light-18-pro zramswapon[2048]: swapon: /dev/zram30: swapon failed: Operation not permitted
Mar 09 09:59:46 light-18-pro zramswapon[2048]: swapon: /dev/zram31: swapon failed: Operation not permitted
Mar 09 09:59:46 light-18-pro systemd[1]: zramswap.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Mar 09 09:59:46 light-18-pro systemd[1]: Failed to start Service enabling compressing RAM with zRam.
Mar 09 09:59:46 light-18-pro systemd[1]: zramswap.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 09 09:59:46 light-18-pro systemd[1]: zramswap.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Do you have an idea what is the issue can be with it? How it can be solved?

Comment: Do you have other swap devices in use at the same time? (Oh right, there's one more in the list.)

Comment: but `zram` compacts the `swap` partition by creation a number(=cores) of virtual devices, no?

Comment: mm, you can create one or swap devices on zram. (Or use them for something else, I guess.) I don't know how, exactly they're tied to cores, if at all, but it's just the userspace scripts that create a number of them.

Comment: Zram uses threads now, so if your goal is not to create 32 separate ram drives but maximize performance of zram swap -- you can create just one device. The fact that threads are working is demonstrated to me routinely by htop. My potato laptop has only 2gb of ram in it, and in heavy swap situations htop happily shows me all 4 cores working their silicone butts off to compress the data as fast as they can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The man page for the `swapon(2)` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/swapon.2.html) says:

> ERRORS
> EPERM  The caller does not have the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability.  Alternatively, the maximum number of swap files are already in use; see NOTES below.
>
> NOTES
> There is an upper limit on the number of swap files that may be used, defined by the kernel constant MAX_SWAPFILES.  Before kernel 2.4.10, MAX_SWAPFILES has the value 8;  since
> kernel  2.4.10,  it  has  the value 32.  Since kernel 2.6.18, the limit is decreased by 2 (thus: 30) if the kernel is built with the CONFIG_MIGRATION option (which reserves two
> swap table entries for the page migration features of mbind(2) and migrate_pages(2)).  Since kernel 2.6.32, the limit is further decreased by 1 if the kernel is built with  the
> CONFIG_MEMORY_FAILURE option.

So, assuming all those options are enabled (check your kernel config), the limit is 32 - 2 - 2 - 1 = 27. Which just so happens to be the exact amount of swap devices you have in use, based on the `lsblk` output (`sda3` + `zram0` to `zram25`). (I've no idea why the error involved is EPERM, "Permission Denied", and not e.g. ENFILE or something else that implies "too many".)

You might be able to increase that limit by recompiling the kernel, but I would just modify the zram scripts to create fewer swap devices. The idea with creating one for each core is so that there's no contention if more than one core wants to swap at the same time. But... if you have 32 cores trying to swap all at once, it already sounds like trouble, so reducing the number probably doesn't matter much.
You could run benchmarks, of course.

On the Ubuntu system I have at hand, the number of devices to create is set in `/etc/default/zramswap`, as `CORES=4`, that setting is read by the actual setup script, which might or might not be similar in other Linuxen.

Comment: thanks @ilkkachu for the great explanation. I have `/var/lib/systemd/migrated/zramswap` in `opensuse` but it is empty. do you mind pasting a part of this file to facilitate my search maybe?

Comment: @nskalis, the `/etc/default` files in Debian/Ubuntu are just environment variable settings for the tools involved. The actual tool to setup zram seems to be a Bash script in `/usr/sbin/zramswap` that sources those vars. I've no idea with OpenSUSE has, they might have a variant of the same script, but you'll have to check how the settings work.